# Igraph number of connected nodes with specific attribute value

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph:

```
g <- make_empty_graph (2) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 1) %>%
  add_vertices(2, color = 2, "a" = 2) %>%
  add_vertices(2, color = 4, "a" = 3) %>%
  add_edges(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1))
plot(g)
```

Is there a way to find out how many nodes with a value of 2 for the attribute "a" are connected to the node "1"?

[image: Graph IMG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the neighbors of node 1 using `neighbors`  and then test for which ones have "a"=2.

```
NeighborList = neighbors(g, 1)
NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2]
+ 1/6 vertex, from 3502fa5:
[1] 4
```

Comment: How would I get this to output the number of neighbors rather than the specific neighbors?

Comment: change the last line to `length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2])`

Comment: One more question: how would you change the code so that it is applied for all nodes? I tried: NeighborList = neighbors(g) but that doesn't work. And I don't want to list out all the individual nodes. Is there a shortcut to include all the nodes?

Comment: `sapply(V(g), function(x) { 
 NeighborList = neighbors(g, x)
 length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2]) } )`

Comment: It told me:                                                                                                  Error: unexpected symbol in "sapply(V(g), function(x) {NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) length" Am I missing something? I put just the sapply line in without anything else?

Comment: Sorry.  The interface here took out the linefeeds.  Try adding a semicolon like this `sapply(V(g), function(x) { NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) ; length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 2]) } ) `